# What is the limit of $(\cos x)^y$ as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$

Tags: limits

How to  calculate this limit? $$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}(\cos x)^y$$ Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

We have

\begin{align}(\cos y)^x&=\exp(x\ln(\cos y))\\&=\exp(x\ln(1-(1-\cos y)))\\&\sim\exp(x(\cos y-1))\xrightarrow{(x,y)\to(0,0)}1\end{align}

Comment: I want calculate limit $(\cos x)^y$

Comment: You don't see that's the same? : interchange $x$ and $y$.

Comment: No need for approximations, cos goes to 1,ln to 0, 0*0=0, exp(0) = 1